# How do I get my Aside element on the side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that my aside element goes to the side of my page, next to the `<p>` element (I hope I'm making sense). Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Here's a photo and my code:

[image: what my page looks like]

HTML:

```
<aside>
<h4>Beginner Friendly Videos</h4>
    <ul class="aside">
      <li>
      <li>
      <li>
    </ul>       
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.aside {
    float: right;
    margin: 0, 1.5%;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better or add an expected result? Maybe post more code to see what can be

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ into Flexbox. It will save you a lot of hassle down the road as it is MUCH better for formatting than Float.

That being said, I would recommend something along the lines of below.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed pellentesque turpis. Proin blandit, augue in euismod facilisis, lacus arcu bibendum purus, ut interdum libero dui in sapien. Suspendisse convallis imperdiet urna sed consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <aside>
            <ul>
                <li>1
                <li>2
                <l1>3
            </ul>
        </aside>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
aside {
   [Your Styles Here, No Float];
}
```

The result is that the aside is to right right of your p tag. Note that p is inside of a div because it is an inline element. You didn't provide all of your code so I cant provide the exact code for you, however if you adjust the width for the nested div and aside, and implement this it should work for you!

If you want the aside on the left, just place it before the nested div.